# webservice(.asmx ) page is not loading in IE but working in firefox and crome

Tags: web-services, internet-explorer, iis, asmx

I have deployed web service in client's virtual machine. which contains .asmx extension. when I paste that URL into IE it gives me 404 page not found error but it working in Firefox and chrome.

IIS VERSION 8.5
IE VERSION 11.0

I try with below Steps:-

1. Give full access to IIS directory.
2. Add IIS_IUSRS with read and execute permission.
3. add CROS in web.config (allow origins for domains and
   content-header.
4. disable firewall setting.

But could not able to resolve. It would be helpful for me if someone can look into this.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Please, show me request headers and response headers of IE and Chrome to comparate.

Comment: solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more than 30 hours Finally I got the solution for my question. Actually when I host services separately (not inside default website) it gives me Issue which I have mention above but when I deploy it inside the default website it works for me.

Thanks,